# Shell parameter expansion with file path - "No such directory"

Tags: bash

I need to ensure a directory is always created lowercase, regardless of what the user inputs. Here's some sample inputs:

```
./1A_Internal/foo/bar/baz/
./External/wizz/bang/baz/
./Validated/bink/bank/bonk/ 
./validated/foo/bang/bonk/
```

(I have no control over input, I just need to accommodate whatever comes in)

In this case, I need *only* `Validated` to be converted into lowercase `validated`. Everything else needs to stay the case it is.

Assuming the path is stored in a variable `location`, I thought this would be:

```
location=$($location/Validated/validated)
```

but I get either `Bad substitution`, or in some cases 
`-bash: ./Validated/bink/bank/bonk//Validated/validated: No such file or directory` depending on how I tweak it.

I looked for awk or sed solutions but again everything seems to trip up on the fact that my variable has `/`'s. I'm open to any solution that will work in bash.

My current thought is grepping the string for case-insensitive "validated", using awk to split it if found, and re-connecting it with lowercase validated (even if it already was lowercase), but this seems so complicated - is there not something easier?

Comment: You probably meant `location=${location/Validated/validated}`. Alternatively (Bash 4.0 or newer), `location=${location,,}` (lowercases everything).

Comment: Which words exactly have to be lowercased? Why `Validated`, but not `External`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. oh man you're totally right, I assumed the variable had to be expanded but I guess not - that does it! As to your question... dunno! Not my choice, I got handed this file system and am now stuck with it